# How to pass two argument in onclick event like id and title with JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, php, oneclick

**I FIX THAT WITH**

```
confirmReset(\''.$nodetitle.', '.$nodeid.'\')
```

**Question :**

I want to run a simple JavaScript function on a if user press the button, alert confirm show the `ID` and `TITLE` of page and Finaly redirect the custom url
my problem is just `ID` have passed and `Title` not!

**Variables**

```
$nodetitle = "Title one";
$nodeid = 150;
```

**HTML**

```
<button class="btn" onclick="return confirmReset('.$nodetitle.', '.$nodeid.');">
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function confirmReset(nodetitle, nodeid) {
 var r = confirm('Node with ( ' + nodeid + nodetitle + ' ) Delete?');
 var url = window.location.pathname;
 var pathArray = url.split( '/' );
 var host = pathArray[1];

 if (r == true) {
    document.location.href = 'node/'  + nodeid + '/delete';
 } else {
   // alert('it didnt work');
 }
 return false;
}
```

**this code just return numbers like `Nodeid` and `nodetitle` NOT returned**

Thanks for you help my friends...

Comment: Are **$nodetitle** & **$nodeid** `php` variables? If so then you need to echo them into the function call. `onclick="return confirmReset('<?php echo $nodetitle; ?>','<?php echo $nodeid; ?>');"`

Comment: yes boths are php variables

Comment: Please replace your button with the below :-

**<button class="btn" onclick="return confirmReset('<?php echo $nodetitle; ?>', '<?php echo $nodeid;?>');">**

Comment: Before that i use print like : print '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-block " onclick="return confirmReset('.$agahinid.', '.$agahinid.');"> BUT DONT WORK !

Comment: FIRST ARGUMENT HAVE BEEN PASSED BUT NODETITLE NOT !

Comment: Try quoting your string value - `<button class="btn" onclick="return confirmReset(\''.$nodetitle.'\', '.$nodeid.');">`.  Note, need to escape the single quotes as it looks like you are building code in php

Comment: @Zandb with the changes I have suggested this seems to display/pass both variables. [**PasteBin**](https://pastebin.com/MsJ9Wcma)

Comment: Nodetitle is not passed ! Apparently the problem is string variable !

Comment: Do this: `<?php var_dump($nodeid)?>;` and result? put this before your `html`

Comment: @Pedram Result:150

Comment: Okay so it's correct, right? So it should work. try this `<button class="btn" onclick="return confirmReset('<?=$nodetitle;?>', '<?=$nodeid;?>');">`

Comment: @Zandb if you mean you want the title to be passed within the redirection then you must include it into the url.

Comment: @NewToJS no. just print nodetitle in alert confirm

Comment: @Pedram is not work!

Comment: I saw your comments now, so you said, `nodeid` return true, just `nodetitle` right? what about `<?php var_dump($nodetitle)?>;`

Comment: RESULT : string(8) "TITLE one"

Comment: So it can't be `empty` on your `html`, it is `string` and has `value`. So last work: use this `<button class="btn" onclick="return confirmReset('<?=$nodetitle;?>', '<?=$nodeid;?>');">` then refresh your page, then go check `errorlog` and let me know the result. before that, delete your previous errorlog.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: Just nodetitle that have numbers can work !!!

Comment: Odd! Try to fix `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list ` error then check again

Comment: I FIX THAT WITH confirmReset(\''.$nodetitle.', '.$nodeid.'\') ---thanks guys...

Comment: I removed  [Solved] in an edit. Posting your own answer and marking it as solved marks it as solved. Either that, or delete the post.

Answer (score 0):

> PHP

```
<?php
$nodetitle = "Title one";
$nodeid = 150;
?>
```

> HTML

```
<button class="btn" onclick="return confirmReset('
<?php echo $nodetitle;?>', '
<?php echo $nodeid;?>');">
    Hello World
</button>
```

> Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function confirmReset(nodetitle, nodeid) {
        var r = confirm('Node with ( ' + nodeid +', '+ nodetitle + ' ) Delete?');
        var url = window.location.pathname;
        var pathArray = url.split( '/' );
        var host = pathArray[1];
        if (r == true) {
            document.location.href = 'node/'  + nodeid + '/delete';
        }
        else {
            // alert('it didnt work');
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>
```